# Negation of progressive tenses in questions

Tags: syntactic-analysis, questions, negation, present-progressive

I want to conjugate the verb "accept" in the progressive form for past, present and future tenses AS A QUESTION IN THE NEGATIVE. But I am confused about which approach is correct:

Scenario: Given the pair of verb and object (accept,challenge),  form the questions for all types of personal pronouns.

So here I go:

**PAST**:

> 1. Was I/she/he not accepting the challenge?

and

> 2. Were  we/you/they  not accepting the challenge?

OR

> 1. Wasn't [Was not] I/she/he accepting the challenge?

and

> 2. Weren't [Were not] we/you/they accepting the challenge?

**PRESENT:**

> 1. Am I not accepting the challenge?

and

> 2. Is he/she not accepting the challenge?

and

> 3. Are we/you/they not accepting the challenge?

OR

> 1. Am not I accepting the challenge?

and

> 2. Isn't [Is not] he/she accepting the challenge?

and

> 3. Aren't [Are not] we/you/they accepting the challenge?

**FUTURE:**

> 1. Will I/he/she/we/you/they not be accepting the challenge?

OR

> 2. Will I/he/she/we/you/they be not accepting the challenge?

Simply put, I want to create regular questions using the progressive tenses. I am a bit confused of where to put the NOT expression within the question, either directly before the progressive form of the verb (here "accepting") OR directly after the appropriately conjugated "to be" expression?

Thank you!